# Online collection of small public video files encoded with different codecs for testing purposes

Tags: video, codec

I'm trying to spot a bug in a video player and I suspect that it's related to a particular codec.
Is there a site that contains a collection of small public-domain video snippets (1-2 MB) encoded with misc video codecs for testing purposes?

Comment: sorry, website questions are offtopic on Super User.

Answer (score 2):

Archive.org has hundreds of thousands of videos which are in the public domain, which are in a TON of different formats.